# Key in list() created with paste()

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

```
library(openxlsx)

x <- data.frame(colx = c(1:5),
                col = c(2:6))

y <- data.frame(coly = c(1:5),
                col = c(2:6))

z <- data.frame(colz = c(1:5),
                col = c(2:6))

a <- list(one9 = x,
     two9 = y,
     three9 = z)

write.xlsx(a) #gives 3 sheets (named: one9, two9, three9) in 1 file
```

But I would like to make the 9 a variable, this way I can easily change the number one time instead of (in this case) three times

So I tried this

```
number <- 9
a <- list(paste0("one", number) = x,
     paste0("two", number) = y,
     paste0("three", number) = z)

write.xlsx(a)
```

However this gives an error, I also tried with assign(), but that just ignores the sheetnames completely. And just names the sheets: sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3

Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your list using e.g. `setNames`:

```r
x <- data.frame(colx = c(1:5),
                col = c(2:6))

y <- data.frame(coly = c(1:5),
                col = c(2:6))

z <- data.frame(colz = c(1:5),
                col = c(2:6))

number <- 9
a <- setNames(list(x, y, z), paste0(c("one", "two", "three"), number))
a
#> $one9
#>   colx col
#> 1    1   2
#> 2    2   3
#> 3    3   4
#> 4    4   5
#> 5    5   6
#> 
#> $two9
#>   coly col
#> 1    1   2
#> 2    2   3
#> 3    3   4
#> 4    4   5
#> 5    5   6
#> 
#> $three9
#>   colz col
#> 1    1   2
#> 2    2   3
#> 3    3   4
#> 4    4   5
#> 5    5   6
```